# Remove border from charts inside a map R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tmap

I am trying to add some pie charts inside a map in the following way:

```
  library(tmaptools)
  library(ggplot2) 
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(tmap)
  library(sf)
  data(NLD_prov)
  
  origin_data <- NLD_prov %>% 
    st_set_geometry(NULL) %>% 
    mutate(FID= factor(1:n())) %>% 
    select(FID, origin_native, origin_west, origin_non_west) %>% 
    gather(key=origin, value=perc, origin_native, origin_west, origin_non_west, factor_key=TRUE)
  
  origin_cols <- get_brewer_pal("Dark2", 3)
  
  grobs <- lapply(split(origin_data, origin_data$FID), function(x) {
    ggplotGrob(ggplot(x, aes(x="", y=-perc, fill=origin)) +
                 geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
                 coord_polar("y", start=0) +
                 scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
                 scale_fill_manual(values=origin_cols) +
                 theme_ps(plot.axes = FALSE)) 
    

    
  })
  
  names(grobs) <- NLD_prov$name
  
  tm_shape(NLD_prov) +
    tm_polygons(group = "Provinces") +
    tm_symbols(size=1, shape="name", 
               shapes=grobs, 
               scale=1, 
               legend.shape.show = FALSE, 
               shapes.legend = 22) +
    tm_add_legend(type="fill", 
                  col=origin_cols, 
                  labels=c("Native", "Western", "Non-western"), 
                  title="Origin") +
    tm_format("NLD")
```

However, I have not been able to remove the black border around the pie charts. I have tried adding several modifications to the theme with no success. How can I remove those borders?

Comment: Can you please add the `library()` calls to the top of your script? This script requires a lot of packages.

Comment: I added the libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border.lwd = NA` as an argument to `tm_symbols()`. The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.3-1/topics/tm_symbols) states:

> border.lwd: line width of the symbol borders. If NA, no symbol borders
> are drawn.